# OSX: find moved file

Tags: macos, filesystems

Some MacOSX applications like iTunes don't really have problems when I move a file around - they still find the moved file easily (and I'm pretty sure they have not have opened the file before).

How are they doing it? One possibility I could think of is the FS event notification system. ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645321/how-to-dectect-new-or-modified-files-in-mac-osx))

But I remember that I have seen some absolute file handle / id or so and I thought that maybe they can always query the current file name by that file handle. Is there something like that? Maybe the inode nr but that is a bit too less because I'm not sure how to get the filename from an inode nr and how to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Albert mentioned Alias Manager has been depreciated, the replacement is the [URL Bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initByResolvingBookmarkData%3aoptions%3arelativeToURL%3abookmarkDataIsStale%3aerror%3a) methods

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about the [Alias Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html) which sounds like what I am searching for. Unfortunately, that seems deprecated. ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673601/locate-file-after-move)) [Some info about the deprecation.](https://github.com/nathanday/ndalias/issues/3)

([Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468394/keep-a-reference-to-a-file-after-it-has-moved-in-objective-c)) There is also the [NSURL class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which provides such functions.

Python code:

```
import AppKit

def getFileNativeId(filepath):
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath): return None
    filepath = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    filepath = unicode(filepath)

    url = AppKit.NSURL.alloc().initFileURLWithPath_(filepath)   

    bookmark = url.bookmarkDataWithOptions_includingResourceValuesForKeys_relativeToURL_error_(AppKit.NSURLBookmarkCreationPreferFileIDResolution,None,None,None)
    bytes = bookmark[0].bytes().tobytes()

    return bytes

def getPathByNativeId(fileid):
    nsdata = AppKit.NSData.alloc().initWithBytes_length_(fileid, len(fileid))
    url, _, _ = AppKit.NSURL.URLByResolvingBookmarkData_options_relativeToURL_bookmarkDataIsStale_error_(nsdata, AppKit.NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI, None,None,None)

    if not url: return None

    return unicode(url.path())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s bookmarks — I'm on an iPad do unable to produce proper links due to Apple's shortsighted web page design but the essence of it is that you obtain a bookmark from a URL and can subsequently resolve a bookmark back to a URL. The system works around any movements in the file in the interim.